# Using chromium webdriver under selenium on ubuntu ARM64

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, apple-m1, utm

I am running an ubuntu 22.04 ARM64 UTM virtual machine on an Apple M1 mini. I am trying to get chromedriver running via python on this ARM64 architecture using this code snippet:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def myFunc(URL):
    webDriver = None

    try:
        chrome_driver_path = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
        chromeOptions = Options()
        chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless=new")
        chromeOptions.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        chromeOptions.binary_location = chrome_driver_path
        webDriver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)  <----- This line fails
        webDriver.get(URL)

        Do something....

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        if webDriver != None:
            webDriver.close()
            webDriver = None

    return webDriver
```

I installed chromium and chromedriver using:
sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver

and the versions of chromium and chromedriver are:
Chromium 122.0.6261.94 snap
ChromeDriver 122.0.6261.94 (880dbf29479c6152d5e4f08dfd3a96b30f919e56-refs/branch-heads/6261@{#960})

1. I have verified I can run the chromedriver at /usr/bin/chromedriver
2. I have tried not supplying the binary path to the chromedriver

The code throws an exception at the indicate line:
'Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location